# CakePHP 2: In $this->Model->delete($id) delete the hasmany model in 'dependent' => false

Tags: database, cakephp, dependencies, models

I have a weird behavior in CakePHP 2.1.5

When I delete a Justification, deletes two things. The justification and the DocumentsProduct associated.

Justifications Controller:

```
class JustificationsController extends AppController {

  public function delete($id = null) {

    $this->Justification->id = $id;
    if ($this->Justification->delete()) {                        
      $valorNull = null;
      $this->Justification->DocumentsProduct->updateAll(
        array('DocumentsProduct.justification_id' => $valorNull),
        array('DocumentsProduct.justification_id' => $id));
    }
  }
}
```

Justification Model:

```
public $hasMany = array(
  'DocumentsProduct' => array(
    'className' => 'DocumentsProduct',
    'foreignKey' => 'justification_id',
    'dependent' => false,
    'conditions' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => '',
    'limit' => '',
    'offset' => '',
    'exclusive' => '',
    'finderQuery' => '',
    'counterQuery' => ''
    )
  );
```

DocumentsProduct Model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(  
  'Justification' => array(
    'className' => 'Justification',
    'foreignKey' => 'justification_id',
    'conditions' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'order' => ''
    )
);
```

So, if I delete a Justification in the justification/delete view, deletes both, Justification and DocumentProduct. But the dependent is in false.
I try $this->Justification->delete($id, false), but still deletes DocumentsProduct.

What I am doing wrong?

UPDATE: THIS IS A PART OF THE qUERY LOG:

```
(int) 130 => array(
        'query' => 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `icorvera_sgcp`.`approvals_documents_products` AS `ApprovalsDocumentsProduct`   WHERE `ApprovalsDocumentsProduct`.`id` = '52d00c27-4d84-47bc-9c47-169cc4460461'',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 1
    ),
    (int) 131 => array(
        'query' => 'DELETE `ApprovalsDocumentsProduct` FROM `icorvera_sgcp`.`approvals_documents_products` AS `ApprovalsDocumentsProduct`   WHERE `ApprovalsDocumentsProduct`.`id` = '52d00c27-4d84-47bc-9c47-169cc4460461'',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 1
    ),
    (int) 132 => array(
        'query' => 'DELETE `DocumentsProduct` FROM `icorvera_sgcp`.`documents_products` AS `DocumentsProduct`   WHERE `DocumentsProduct`.`id` = '52d00c27-a1f4-4756-a126-169cc4460461'',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 1
    ),
    (int) 133 => array(
        'query' => 'DELETE `Justification` FROM `icorvera_sgcp`.`justifications` AS `Justification`   WHERE `Justification`.`id` = '529e1dbc-bbc0-4be1-828d-09c8c4460461'',
        'params' => array(),
        'affected' => (int) 1,
        'numRows' => (int) 1,
        'took' => (float) 1
    )
),
'count' => (int) 134,
'time' => (float) 343
)
```

Comment: Do you have in database linking between tables?

Comment: Nope. Also I get the log of the cake's querys

Comment: Could you add ApprovalsDocumentsProduct model relations ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

After some investigation, I noticed that in the database itself I have made a 'cascade' action for 'onDelete" event. This was overwriting the cakephp behavior.